# C[0,1] is an infinity dimensional space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to show that $C[0,1]$ is an infinity dimensional space, if I can find two norms (in C[0,1]) that are not equivalents, it have been proved. But in another way, if let that: 
$$B=\left\{f_1,f_2,...,f_n\right\}$$ is a basis of $C[0,1]$, I think that $f1\cdot f_2\cdot...\cdot f_n\notin span(B)$.

It is true?. How can prove it?

Thank You.

Comment: Do monomials form an independent set?  (Powers of $x$?)

Comment: Yes, but I think that this set does not necessarily generate space.

Comment: @AndrésFelipe: By Weierstrass approximation theorem, any continuous function in $[0,1]$ is uniformly approximated by a sequence of polynomials.

Comment: The monomials don't need to generate the space (although the subspace spanned by them is dense in the usual $\infty$-norm).  All that is necessary is that there are infinitely many and the collection is linearly independent.

Comment: ... and that can be checked by recalling that a Vandermonde matrix is invertible iff generated by distinct elements.

Comment: The dimension of $C[0,1]$ is at least the dimension of the span of polynomials, which is infinite.

Comment: @jackD'Aurizio: thank you, I had forgotten that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that doesn't necessarily work, because there are examples of arbitrarily large finite linearly independent sets whose product is in the set (hence in the span).  E.g., $\left\{1, 1+x, 1+x^2,\ldots, 1+x^{n}, \dfrac{1}{(1+x)(1+x^2)\cdots(1+x^n)}\right\}$ is linearly independent, and its product is $1$, which is in the set.

As commenters have pointed out, the linearly independent set $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$ demonstrates that $C[0,1]$ has infinite dimension.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say that: $$f_1\cdot f_2\cdot ...\cdot f_n\notin span(B)$$

Comment: No problem; beyond that misspeaking, my main point was that a product of linearly independent elements could still be in the span of the elements, and can even be one of the elements.  I'll edit now that you've edited.